# AngularJs, is it possible to ng-insert a data taken from $scope array?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this javascript code:

```
app.controller('Ctrl',[ '$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.poems =[
                    {title:"title1", author:"author1", file:"URLfile1"},
                    {title:"title2", author:"author2", file:"URLfile2"},
                    {title:"title3", author:"author3", file:"URLfile3"}
                    ];
}]);
```

into the html I'd like to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat ="poem in poems">
   <h1>{{poem.title}}</h1>
   <p>{{poem.author}}</p>
   <div ng-include="{{poem.file}}"></div>
</div>
```

but this doesn't seem to work.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is URLfile1? Is it a html file? If so is it located in the same path as the html file you posted?

Comment: Yes it's a html file. In the same path

Answer (score 0):

Then you could try this

```
<div ng-include src="{{poem.file}}"></div>
```

That might possibly work.

Comment: Check what is the value got by `{{poem.file}}` in the inspect element.

Comment: Nothing. I don't get any value. It's blank

Comment: You should check your `$scope.poems` by putting a console.log whether it has any value for file attribute.

Comment: the error in the console is too long, but it says it's a parse thing.
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bpoem.file%7D%7D&p4=%7Bpoem.file%7D%7D

Comment: I found it by myself. It's <div ng-include src="poem.file"></div>. Without brackets

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
<div ng-include src="poem.file"></div>
```

without brackets